# Visual Studio & SharePoint distant Server

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

I have VisualStudio 2015 on my computer and i would like to connect it in SharePoint Server which is put on another computer (Using VM)

I know that, VS works only with SP in local.

Is it possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connect it"?

Comment: connect my VS to a Sharepoint Server.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. What do you mean by "connect?" What are you ultimately trying to do? For example, are you trying to publish SharePoint solutions from Visual Studio on your local computer to a remote SharePoint environment? Are you trying to use the quick deploy/debug feature in Visual Studio to debug a SharePoint solution? Are you just trying to develop a SharePoint solution and it's telling you that you need SharePoint installed?

Comment: I want to try to publish SharePoint Solutions from Visual Studio to remote SP environment. (If by remote you mean, SP installed on another computer and not on mine, then that's it ! )

Answer (score 0):

One option is to publish the solution locally. For a farm solution, publishing from Visual Studio will produce a .wsp file.

You can then copy that file to the computer with SharePoint installed on it, and use Powershell (running on the remote computer) to deploy it in to SharePoint via the `add-spsolution` and `install-spsolution` cmdlets.

For more detailed information and instructions, you can refer to Microsoft's documentation here: [**Install and manage solutions for SharePoint 2013**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263205.aspx).